# SparkContext.setLogLevel("DEBUG") doesn't works in Cluster

Tags: apache-spark, log4j, pyspark, spark-streaming, rdd

I'm trying to control my Spark logs use 
            sc.setLogLevel("ERROR");
seems like it doesn't work in the cluster environment. Can anyone help?

```
public static JavaSparkContext getSparkContext(String appName, SparkConf conf) {
    SparkSession spark = getSparkSession(appName, conf);
    JavaSparkContext sc = new JavaSparkContext(spark.sparkContext());
    sc.setLogLevel("WARN");
    return sc;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To configure log levels, add the following options to your spark submit command:

```
'--conf "spark.driver.extraJavaOptions=-Dlog4j.configuration=custom-log4j.properties"'

'--conf "spark.executor.extraJavaOptions=-Dlog4j.configuration=custom-log4j.properties"'
```

This assumes you have a file called custom-log4j.properties on the classpath. This log4j can then control the verbosity of spark's logging.

Comment: Is there have any solution that only manipulates the logs in my logic code part? that I don't want to attach the configuration files and submit script.

Comment: As you are changing the Log level on driver the executors won't be able to reflect those changes. Execute something like below: `sc.parallelize(Seq("")).foreachPartition(x => {
  import org.apache.log4j.{LogManager, Level}
  import org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory

  LogManager.getRootLogger().setLevel(Level.DEBUG)
  val log = LogFactory.getLog("EXECUTOR-LOG:")
  log.debug("START EXECUTOR DEBUG LOG LEVEL")
})`

Comment: You can refer details on: [databricks.com](https://docs.databricks.com/spark/latest/faq/setting-log-level-on-executors.html)

Comment: Thanks, sounds interesting, i can try now. But in java how can i import those things in the foreachpartition "import org.apache.log4j.Logger;
import org.apache.log4j.Level;"?

Comment: Simply create Logger object and import the classes on driver level. Executors serialization does it for you. Please upvote if you find it useful.

Comment: Thanks a lot . it wortks,